# Save data from Django Python form to database

Tags: django, database, forms, input, save

Okay so I have read two previous posts on this subject here but did not help me out all too much, went over to Django tutorial, also did not find a solution. 
I have a bad feeling I am doing something really stupid here.

I have a form where I input data on the site and no matter what I do I cannot get them to save to a database

Setup:
OS:Fedora 
IDE: eclipse
Django 1.9  Python 2.7
Default Django DB

CODE:

new.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Create a New One</h1>
            <form method='post' action="/home/"> {% csrf_token %}
                <table>
                    {{ formset.as_p }}
                </table>
            </form>

                <input type='submit' value="Submit">
    </body>
</html>
```

Viwes.py

```
def home(request):
    form = NewForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
    context = {
        "formset" : form
    }
    return render(request, "secondTry/new.html", context)
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from secondTry.models import New


class NewForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = New
        fields = [
                  "firstName", 
                  "lastName", 
                  "email"
                  ]
```

models.py

```
class New(models.Model):
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_unicode(self.firstName)
```

Everything displays as it should on the site when I open it and I can write data into forms but when I click the Submit button, it does not save it to the database.

I have tried my best to explain my problem, if you require further info please ask.

Thank you all for your time and effort.

Comment: Have you tried putting the submit button inside the `<form> </form>` tags?

Comment: It goes through after putting it into form tags (this was stupid, on my end) but nothing is inserted (saved) into the database.

Comment: <form><input type='submit' value="Submit"></form>

Comment: Thank you Curtis Olson for your time I have figured it out, it was the form tags just was writing them in a improper manner. Thank you so much for your time.